# Push notification sound not heard if audio already playing on iPhone

Tags: iphone

using sdk 4.1 . The wav file that is played when a push notification arrives on the device plays fine when no audio is being played on the iphone but if there is audio being played it is not heard. Is there any way of getting it to play superimposed on the existing audio , even if it sounds quieter that is ok.

Comment: No idea if 4.2 fixes your problem, but you should *always* build against the current SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the Default sound? Does it work in that case?